# Can CSS animate or transition be used on the flex-direction property?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions, css-animations

If an ordered list uses `flex-direction: column` on small screens and `flex-direction: row` on larger screens, can CSS3 animations or transitions animate the `flex-direction` property between media queries?

**Initial page set up**

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
ol a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  ol {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  ol a {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav 4</a></li>
</ol>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYGexa

**Similar animation in JavaScript**

```js
'use strict';
console.clear();
var group = document.querySelector('.group');
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
var total = nodes.length;
var ease = Power1.easeInOut;
var boxes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
        break;
    }
    var node = nodes[i];
    TweenLite.set(node, { x: 0 });
    boxes[i] = {
        transform: node._gsTransform,
        x: node.offsetLeft,
        y: node.offsetTop,
        node: node
    };
}
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
group.addEventListener('mouseenter', layout);
group.addEventListener('mouseleave', layout);
function layout() {
    group.classList.toggle('reorder');
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        var box = boxes[i];
        var lastX = box.x;
        var lastY = box.y;
        box.x = box.node.offsetLeft;
        box.y = box.node.offsetTop;
        if (lastX === box.x && lastY === box.y)
            continue;
        var x = box.transform.x + lastX - box.x;
        var y = box.transform.y + lastY - box.y;
        TweenLite.fromTo(box.node, 0.5, {
            x: x,
            y: y
        }, {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            ease: ease
        });
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 24px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.group {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 126px;
  height: 126px;
}
.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.6);
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.6);
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.6);
}
.box:nth-child(4) {
  background: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.6);
}

.group.reorder {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hover to change flex direction</h1>

<div class="group">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/eJGrPN?editors=0010

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, only properties using quantified values of compatible units can transition between two of those values, like measurements and colors.

Answer (score 5):

You cant like already anwserd, but there are took  [tweenlite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite)

```
TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener("tick", () => dirty && layout());
```

Here is one example for you [Codepen](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/dMLQJr).

Comment: How about a simple example code showing how to  animate flex-direction?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. `flex-direction` is not an animatable property in CSS.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 1):

As already anwsered, `flex-direction` can't be animated directly, and browsers "have no idea" how to interpolate the positions of flex items visually during such transition. But you can kind of emulate such transition by transitioning transforms and changing `flex-direction` on `transitionend` event (a quick demo to illustrate the idea: http://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/ZBXrXV/).