# Change the flex-direction on button click

Tags: javascript, css, button, css-animations

I am trying to create an animation effect that moves two buttons when I click on them. I have the flex direction set up as a column in  the container div and I essentially just want them to position as a flex row when I click on one of them (probably with a 1s animation). When I click on them currently nothing happens. Here is my code sample:

HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Choose Your Allegiance</h1>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button class="fill"><img src="/assets/Jedi.png" alt="Jedi" /></button>
    <button class="fill sith">
      <img src="/assets/Sith.png" alt="Sith" />
    </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container.click {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 5vw;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Poller One", cursive;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 6vh;
}

button {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.25s;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: black;
}

.fill {
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.fill:hover,
.fill:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4.5em #add8e6;
}

.sith:hover,
.sith:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4.5em black;
}

#buttons {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

JS

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle(".container.click");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of changes you need to make to get this to work:

**1. `document.querySelector("button")` is only selecting the first button.** There are 2 you can add an event listener to the buttons

1. use `document.querySelectorAll("button")` to get all the buttons, and then you can loop through them adding an event Listener to each one:

```
    document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("click");
      });
    });
```

2. A better way is to add an event listener to the `buttons` container - you can get the element using `getElementById` and then add the listener to it:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
buttons.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("click");
});
```

**2. You just use the class name when passing a class into `toggle`**- you don't need the `.`. Also, you only need to toggle the `click` class as the `container` class will always apply. So what you need to use is `.toggle("click");`

**Working Example** (without your images):

```js
var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
buttons.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("click");
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container.click {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 5vw;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Poller One", cursive;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 6vh;
}

button {
  color: red;
  transition: 0.25s;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: black;
}

.fill {
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.fill:hover,
.fill:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4.5em #add8e6;
}

.sith:hover,
.sith:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4.5em black;
}

#buttons {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Choose Your Allegiance</h1>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button class="fill">Jedi</button>
      <button class="fill sith">Sith</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

As for animating this change, unfortunately [CSS animations cannot be applied to flexbox direction property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855837/can-css-animate-or-transition-be-used-on-the-flex-direction-property).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the detailed response. I am having fun learning all this!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `classList.toggle` wrong. You'll need to do this instead:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.classList.toggle("click");
```

[Documentation on `Element.classList` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).