# Keep constraints between two elements when one is getting off screen

Tags: html, css

I would like an element "1" to go off screen (off red square in my example) and to be followed by an element "2" without having to use anything else than CSS constraints.

```js
const right = document.getElementById('right');
const left = document.getElementById('left');

function r(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

right.style.width = `${r(10, 30)}%`;
left.style.width = `${r(10, 30)}%`;

left.onclick = () => {
    left.classList.toggle('retracted');
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50vw;
    top: 50vh;
    border: 3px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    resize: horizontal;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.left {
    background-color: rgb(95, 158, 160, 0.5);
}

.left.retracted {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.right {
    background-color: rgb(255, 228, 196, 0.5);
    right: 0;
}

.filler {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <title>Slide</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="left" class="panel left">
            1
        </div>

        <div id="right" class="panel right">
            2
        </div>

        <div class="filler"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can do this by hand by computing sizes and everything I want in js but it's not my goal, I was wondering if there was any way to keep constraints between these two elements and keep the animation.

I only do:

```
right.style.width = `${r(10, 30)}%`;
left.style.width = `${r(10, 30)}%`;
```

this to simulate the fact that the two elements does not have the same size and that I'm looking for a self-compute-less solution.

Comment: Do you mean the elements to go out of a container or to go out of the viewport (both scenarios are hinted at in your question).

Comment: do you want to change the position ? or disappear is acceptable too?

Comment: The goal is to stick "2" to the edge of the red square at the end of the animation @AHaworth

Comment: It needs to be a slide animation @M.RMRF

Comment: Thanks, I'd misunderstood what was required so have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

---

Using variables will solve width problem.

Basically you are using variables to make right container move as left container.

---

```
:root{
  --left-width: 30%;
  --right-width: 50%;
  --left-value:30;
  --right-value:50;
}

.right.retracted{
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% * var(--left-value) / var(--right-value)));
}
```

---

```js
const leftContainer = document.querySelector('.left');
const rightContainer = document.querySelector('.right');

leftContainer.onclick = () => {
    rightContainer.classList.toggle('retracted');
    leftContainer.classList.toggle('retracted');
    
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin:0;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  margin:auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: start;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  resize: horizontal;
  user-select: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}

:root{
  --left-width: 30%;
  --right-width: 50%;
  --left-value:30;
  --right-value:50;
}

.left {
  width: var(--left-width);
  background-color: rgb(95, 158, 160, 0.5);
}
.left.retracted{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all .2s; 
}

.right {
  width:var(--right-width);
  background-color: rgb(255, 228, 196, 0.5);
}

.filler {
  flex: 1;
}

.right.retracted{
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% * var(--left-value) / var(--right-value)));
  transition: all .2s; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="panel left">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel right">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>

      <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got you, but "2" doesn't follow the animation, it just jumps right to the edge

Comment: You can't animate flex container position behaviour.  Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855837/can-css-animate-or-transition-be-used-on-the-flex-direction-property

Comment: Actually i don't understand what you are looking for. Are you okay with using JS ? or looking for a solution only CSS? @NaoufelBERRADA

Comment: The best solution would be CSS only, I know how to do it using JS but there is too many edge cases in my specfic situation such as window / content resize.

Comment: nevermind i'll just use JS, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Edited the code.  Check that. using `position:absolute` creates problem @NaoufelBERRADA

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer the question either, since the two containers does not necessarily have the same width

Comment: Check the new edit please @NaoufelBERRADA

Answer (score 0):

i put width of `.right` and `.left` into a css variable.
and i useed variables to change the position of elements.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const left = document.getElementById('left');


left.onclick = () => {
    container.classList.toggle('retracted');
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container {
/* maximum width 100% */
  --leftWidth: 15%;
  --rightWidth: 35%;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50vw;
    top: 50vh;
    border: 3px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    resize: horizontal;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.left {
    background-color: rgb(95, 158, 160, 0.5);
    width: var(--leftWidth);
    left:0;
}

.retracted .left {
    left: calc(var(--leftWidth) * -1);
}

.right {
    background-color: rgb(255, 228, 196, 0.5);
    width: var(--rightWidth);
    left:0;
}
.retracted .right{
    left: calc(var(--leftWidth) * -1);

}

.filler {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <title>Slide</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div id="left" class="panel left">
            1
        </div>

        <div id="right" class="panel right">
            2
        </div>

        <div class="filler"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question as the two container clearly have different sizes in my example

Comment: @NaoufelBERRADA different sizes is applied